# Cloud functions - could not handle the request

Tags: node.js, cors, fetch, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to fetch data from third party API (api.pubgtracker.com) by using reverse proxy to add CORS headers to the request.

My index.js looks like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

exports.findPlayer = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
 let nickname = req.query.nickname;
 let region = req.query.region;
 let mode = req.query.mode;

 let requestHeader = {
  method: "GET",
   headers: {
     'my-api-key': 'value-of-my-api-key'
   }
 }

 fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.pubgtracker.com/v2/profile/pc/${nickname}?region=${region}&mode=${mode}`, requestHeader)
   .then(response => response)
   .then(text => {
     res.send(text);
   });
});
```

Problem is that by going to my cloud function, all I get is `"Error: Could not handle the request"` and by looking into logs I see:

```
FetchError: request to https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.pubgtracker.com/v2/profile/pc/VissGames?region=na&mode=solo-fpp failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com:443
```

What's the problem here? I am a pure beginner when it comes to fetching data and I am not able to see what's wrong, despite trying to solve it through solutions other people gave on questions with similar problem.

Comment: try hitting url using postman and are you sure about the url ? I can see two https blocks in the url

Answer (score 1):

I checked whether https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ is working. Your application is complaining `ENOTFOUND` for `cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com:443`. That means it cannot access https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/. This means it does not have proper network connectivity or there's a [problem with your DNS](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/issues/164).

Can provide more help if you give us more data. (Ex : Try accessing a different URL such as google.com)

Comment: Yes, that means your node application does not have Internet access. What's your operating system? May be a firewall is blocking you?

Comment: I am working on Windows 10. My firewall allows node.js as well.

Comment: How do you know? Turn off your firewall for 10 seconds and run the program

Comment: Yup, still nothing.